# How to set up a Google Application Load Balancer for a multi-service App Engine?

Tags: flask, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I have multiple [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com) web applications, each running as a Google App Engine (GAE) service. Each application thus has its own URL (see: [How Requests are Routed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed)). For this example, let's assume I have 3 web applications (one default and two others) with the following URLs:

- https://myproject.uc.r.appspot.com (default)
- https://myservice1.myproject.uc.r.appspot.com (myservice1)
- https://myservice2.myproject.uc.r.appspot.com (myservice2)

Moreover, each URL has its own path system (/login, /home, etc...).

Google recommends some [security features](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/application-security?tab=python) to protect an App Engine, one of which consists in changing the ingress settings to allow requests only from an Application Load Balancer. This allows to have a single entry-point through a [global static IP address](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless#ip-address) on which we can implement [Google Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless#enable-armor) and an [SSL certificate](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless#ssl_certificate_resource).

I have been following the setup procedure described [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless) on how to implement a load balancer with App Engine but I have not been able to understand/implement how a client can access my 3 web applications through a single IP address (e.g. x.x.x.x:80).

Conceptually, clients that enter a certain URL would somehow need be redirected to the appropriate App Engine service, e.g.:

- x.x.x.x:80/default -> https://myproject.uc.r.appspot.com
- x.x.x.x:80/myservice1 -> https://myservice1.myproject.uc.r.appspot.com
- and so on...

However, clients cannot access the appspot.com URLs directly as I've modified the ingress settings.

Is it possible to implement the concept above? If so, how would I need to configure the load balancer? Or do I rather need to have a load balancer per App Engine service?

Comment: Are you saying clients can only access your services by typing in the IP (they can't use a domain name, they can only use the IP)?

Comment: Actually, the end result would be clients typing in a sub-domain name rather than an IP address. A sub-domain would correspond to an App Engine service. I have not explored this path yet.

Comment: What did you try up to now? Where are you stuck?  Because yes, you can do that with serverless NEG and rewrite URL feature

Comment: After digging into the documentation, I've finally found what I was looking for: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless#using-url-mask (URL masks).